# Why Biobert has 499 Input tokens instead of 512?

Tags: bert-language-model, word-embedding, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers, nlp-question-answering

Biobert input sequence length I am getting is 499 inspite of specifying it as 512 in tokenizer?
How can this happen.
Padding and truncation is set to TRUE.
I am working on Squad dataset and for all the datapoints, I am getting input_ids length to be 499.

I tried searching in BIOBERT paper,  but there they have written that it should be 512.